# JPA-override annotation on SuperClass property

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have SuperClass where I have defined my properties and I want to apply one more annotation on  one of the SuperClass Property.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class CartBaseEntity {
private String cartName;

@Column(name = "cart_name")
public String getCartName() {
    return cartName;
 }

public void setCartName(String cartName) {
    this.cartName = cartName;
 }
}
```

And my Sub Class is in below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CART2")
public class CartEntity extends CartBaseEntity implements Serializable {

private Set<Items> items;

@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Override
public String getCartName() {
    return super.getCartName(); 
  }
}
```

I was trying to override the 'cartName' column and want to add **@Basic** annotation on it. Is it possible or is there any workarround? TIA

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it's possible with `@AttributeOverride` annotation applied to a subclass:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CART2")
@AttributeOverride(name = "cartName", column = @Column(name="CART_NAME"))
public class CartEntity extends CartBaseEntity implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

---

UPDATE: here's what JPA 2.1 Specification tells about overriding a column in a mapped superclass:

> **11.1.4 AttributeOverride Annotation**
>
> The `AttributeOverride` annotation is used to override the mapping of
>   a `Basic` (whether explicit or default) property or field or `Id`
>   property or field.
>
> The `AttributeOverride` annotation may be applied to an entity that
>   extends a mapped superclass or to an embedded field or property to
>   override a `Basic` mapping or `Id` mapping defined by the mapped
>   superclass or embeddable class (or embeddable class of one of its
>   attributes).

Comment: If you please carefully look into the code, I wanted to add a new annotation @ Basic on the 'cartName' column. The Super class will not have this @ Basic annotation but the subclass will have this annotation.

Comment: I am afraid it doesn't work like that. JPA specification states that `@AttributeOverride` annotation overrides a column. I have updated my answer with that statement. btw. what prevents you from using it anyway?

Comment: worked great, except for a small syntax issue: for me it was

@AttributeOverride(name = "cartName", column = Column(name="CART_NAME"))

instead of

@AttributeOverride(name = "cartName", column = @Column(name="CART_NAME"))

in other words: the "@" for the new, overriding column has to be omitted!

Comment: does not really work